# Apostille document for from non-apostille countries

Tags: civil-legal-system

I am an indonesian marrying a Mauritian. The marriage will take place in Mauritius. To obtain my residence permit, they are asking for:

> Full Birth Certificate of applicant duly legalized/authenticated by
>   competent authority/ bear the seal of  "Apostille" of the Hague
>   Convention of 5th October 1961 (where applicable).

Indonesia is not part of the `Apostille Convention`, I'm in Indonesia, What should do, is there any other legal document I can use to replace the apostille birth certificate and where should I do this ?

Comment: Right in your quote (where is it from, by the way?) it says "where applicable". If Indonesia doesn't follow the Apostille Convention, ask the country where you're trying to get the residence permit what they will accept.

Comment: Often a certification from a notary public or government official would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of moving to another country for varying reasons, legalization of documents is required. It could be in different forms like **apostille** or **attestation**. Since Mauritius belongs to the **Apostille Hague Convention**, it requires your documents to obtain the **apostille sticker** from the concerned foreign affairs department of the nation. However, Indonesia is not a part of the [apostille countries](https://www.hcch.net/en/states/hcch-members) and hence, does not provide apostille of documents.

In order to get the document legalization from a non-apostille country for an apostille country, the document needs to be **attested from the respective embassy**. In this case, the Birth Certificate authentication can be obtained from the Mauritius embassy based in Indonesia. The embassy won’t be able to provide the apostille sticker but will attest the document by providing a stamp and signature on it. This shall substitute the requirement for apostille birth certificate.